# Can we apply a .css file on a tableau dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a requirement where in i want to use .css (stylesheet) on a Tableau dashboard. Is there a way to do this? I am new to Tableau and have no idea about it. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, unfortunately Tableau doesn't provide tools to do that.

Its layout customization features are pretty extended though, you should be able to build a dashboard looking almost whatever you like, by using horizontal and vertical containers, transparency (from 2018.3 on) and colors and fonts customization.

A good place for inspiration is [Tableau Public](https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/gallery), where you can find great dashboards published by other users. Other references can be found [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/248659).

As mentioned in the link above, if you want to get your hands dirty you can embed a dashboard that's been published on Tableau in a custom page using [Tableau Javascript APIs](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but can we design Dashboard template atleast?

Comment: As far as I know you can design a dashboard with your layout but no content and use that as a starting point for all the new dashboards you're going to create

Comment: @StefanoZanini do you mean that colors and fonts customization for the embedded dashboard should be customized inside Tableau itself and then it will show up with proper colors on webpage?

Comment: @AlexA yes exactly, once the dashboard layout has been customized, it will show with that same formatting wherever you display it (Tableau Desktop, Tableau Server, embedded somewhere else etc)

Answer (score 1):

The longer answer is yes kinda. I was trying to add css animation and figured I could use Tableau Public and the browser addon Stylus. It works well especially for presenting in a meeting or screenshare- but anyone viewing the workbook would also need to be loading your stylesheet via Stylus on Tableau Public. I recorded a vid showing it in action- https://youtu.be/cDTZj7C-EMg